# Setting innerhtml after displaying an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it OK to set the html of the element after the element is displayed. Will the user find any visible difference in this case. For Eg.

```
$("#abc").show();
$("#abc").append("<div>Test div</div>");
```

Also I would like to know if this would cause unwanted browser repaints.

Thanks,
Gautham

Comment: You should try out... But isnt that what Stackoverflow did while you were editing your post? Did you see any visible anomalies? :P

Comment: `.html()` replaces the existing content `#abc`.

Comment: I dont see any visible changes. But would it cause any additional repaints. How can I test that?

Comment: @Jai have use append() now instead of html()

Comment: It shouldn't cause any extra browser repaints unless you're calling `append()` multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this could help: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mVgR5/)

```
$('button').click(function () {
   console.log('Height is ' + $("#abc").height() + ' before show.');
   $("#abc").show();
   console.log('Height is ' + $("#abc").height() + ' after show.');
   $("#abc").append("<div>Test div</div>");
   console.log('Height is ' + $("#abc").height() + ' after filling.');
});
```

outputs:

```
Height is 0 before show.
Height is 0 after show.
Height is 20 after filling.
```

[**browser-reflows-repaint for info**](http://ajaxian.com/archives/browser-reflows-how-do-they-affect-performance)